# pythonのBashのインストールについて

Tags: python, bash

Windows10のPCを使用しています。pythonのBashをインストールしたいのですが、インストールができません。
はじめに、 https://lab.sonicmoov.com/development/windows-bash/ というサイトに沿って行いました。
Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)の有効化をしようと思い、「Windowsの機能の有効化または無効化」を行うと、Windows Subsystem for Linuxにチェックを入れないといけないようなのですが、Windows Subsystem for Linuxのチェックボックスが探してもありません。

どのようにインストールすればいいでしょうか。
初心者で、わからず困っています。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「設定」->「更新とセキュリティ」->「開発者向け」に移動して、「開発者用モード」が「オン」になっているかどうかを確認してみて下さい。

Comment: この辺かもしれません。[WSL2をインストールして使うときの注意点](https://qiita.com/matarillo/items/98d7452967987fe5d633), [Windows 10でLinuxを使う(WSL2)](https://qiita.com/whim0321/items/ed76b490daaec152dc69), [WSL 1 と WSL 2 の比較](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/wsl/compare-versions), [Windows 10 用 Windows Subsystem for Linux のインストール ガイド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/wsl/install-win10), [WSL 開発環境を設定するためのベストプラクティス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/wsl/setup/environment)

Comment: まずは [インストールの要件](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/wsl/install-win10) を確認しているか確認してみてください。バージョンや64bit版等

Comment: ちなみにpythonとbashの間に直接の関連は無く、その上で何故WSLが出てくるか分からないので、「自分が何をしたいか/何をしようとしているか/何のためにその作業や手順を行っているか」についての理解あるいは明確化が不足している感じです。単に言葉足らずで何段階かの作業や手順が端折られているのかもしれませんが、それらを理解していれば今のようなタイトルや最初の文にはならないはず(あるいは日本語ネイティブでは無く機械翻訳ならあり得るかもですが)なので、作業の前にやりたい事やらなければならない事への理解をもっと深めるか、断片的な資料ではなく、従っていれば一通りの知識が得られるようなTutorialやコース的なものを探して履修した方が良いと思われます。